# Practical security question only results in more questions and downvoting

Tags: support, specific-question

My question went wrong [Emails about bank are either scam or a mistake](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/252219/emails-about-bank-are-either-scam-or-a-mistake)

And, completely inconsistent, an almost identical question was accepted [Sent text by bank I don’t have an account with- Is this a scam?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193673/sent-text-by-bank-i-don-t-have-an-account-with-is-this-a-scam?rq=1)

But it is on-topic (about the integrity of data sent on the internet). And about a real problem which won't go away. I'm rather disappointed that there has been no progress for several years and the responses I receieve are completely different from different persons. Something more is wrong here than just my asking.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @schroeder Often it's better to show the problem instead of asking the wrong question

Comment: No, it's not. And certainly not on a Q&A site.... The button says "Ask Question".

Comment: @schroeder It's obvious that a main question is whether the messages are from the real Deutsche Bank or not. That is relevant and was a question which was answered completely arbitrary with no evidence about anything. That is called data integrity to verify that the message is authentic. That is on-topic for security. So you couldn't even answer the first relevant question which was on-topic. Of course I don't ask the second wrong question when the answers are just misleading.

Comment: This post *here* needs to be a question. Do you have a question *here*? Your post here is not a question.

Comment: @schroeder And, completely inconsistent, an almost identical question was accepted https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193673/sent-text-by-bank-i-don-t-have-an-account-with-is-this-a-scam?rq=1
It's obvious that you are completely arbitrary with questions and you had no attempt to solve a problem or help anybody. You are only here to enforce arbitrary local lack of principle for handling questions.

Comment: Actually, that linked question has far more info than you provided. Instead of trying to justify your feelings of frustration with *me*, you could spend 30 seconds answering my clarifying questions. But you are focused on me and not doing *anything* to try and resolve your prolem. So, I'm not responding any more.

Comment: Hi Niklas! I understand you are frustrated at having your question closed. However, after reading the lengthy discussion between you and schroeder, I was left pretty confused as to what you really wanted to ask. As such, closing the question as "Needs details or clarity" seems justified. If you want a chance at having your question reopened, you might want to try editing your question to reformulate it (clarify what you want to know, include all the relevant details in the question body, include relevant details from the email header (whether SPF, DKIM and DMARC failed or not))

Comment: Also, please make sure that what you want is on-topic for Information Security. If you want to know how to make the bank/phisher stop sending those emails, that is not an on-topic infosec concern.

Comment: @nobody Not exactly. I already wrote to the bank about it, who responded that the emails were scam and not from them. It seems to have been not true. The emails appeared to have been from the bank but intended for another person with a similar name, literally the same beginning of the name. Exactly the same happened at my university when I received emails for another guy named Niklas and the email address was my address instead. My question was more about how and what to collect as evidence for my case supporting my hypothesis that the emails were from the bank by mistake. It was not handled

Answer (score 3):

Your original question had no info. There was no context, and it was not something we could help with. Slowly, you've added some information, but it is still unclear. For example, it took 3 days of questions to find out that the emails were not even addressed to you.

The comment section is intended for follow-up questions, so that's not a problem or a fault.

And no, your question is not about "the integrity of data sent on the internet". This is about you getting emails you don't want.

Comment: Your answer has no info about how to solve the problem. The problem is about incoming email messages that seem not right. It's obvious that rephrasing the question or posting more info is not the way to go. You might as well avoid writing here to begin with if you are not going to try and solve the problem.

Comment: Of course my answer doesn't. ***How to solve the problem is not something you asked***. We are not mind readers. You don't have a clear question, you have no clear details, you answer half of the clarifying questions, you don't follow instructions, and you have no clear outcome you want. Yet, you have concluded that all your frusttrations are somehow my fault. So, I'm done. I can't help those who feel they shouldn't have to help themselves. Good luck with the emails.

Comment: After writing to Deutsche Bank 4 or 5 times and calling them on the phone, the emails have stopped coming. That is a strong indication that your statement was not true ("The emails are not from DB.") and that my original hypothesis was in fact true, that I was sent emails from DB in error, emails intended to someone else with a similar name. You complained that my question did not contain info such as email headers. Then when I added email headers you deleted them and you said "We do not analyse email headers". It's more than clear that you wasted everyone's time

Comment: You have failed to understand my comments. There's not much I can do about that. Either way, the question *had nothing to do with information security*. So, it was off-topic.

Comment: Anyway what happened (besides comments) did confirm my hypothesis that the emails was a mistake from the bank. That strengthens the hypothesis that your statement was not true (that the emails are not from the bank). And there was no attempt anywhere on the site to work on the task that I asked about: How can I know that an email message is from the sender or not?

Comment: That was not *my statement*. That;s what *you* said. We can't magically know what's going on. And, no, that wasn't *what you asked*. The whole reason why it was closed was because it wasn't clear what you were askign or what you wanted.